# Using FontAwsome in menu as navigation label shows a square with two rows of numbers (WordPress))

Tags: wordpress, icons, font-awesome

I have zero experience in WordPress and have been searching the web alot for an answer to my problem.

I've seen videos of people using FontAwesome in the navigation label of a custom link in their menu and have tried doing everything they have. I've inserted a code such as this: `<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>` but it shows up as a square with two rows of numbers with 2 digits in each. Have a look here in the nav bar [www.qub.dk](http://qub.dk)

I am using the plugin 'better font awesome' which i am sure is active since i can use it propably on pages.

Any tips will be much appriciated

Comment: I dont't get it. You are loading in fontawesome 4.7 but you're above classnames indicate fontawesome 5. Also I don't see any `<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>` calls on the page you have just linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll either need to change the included fontawesome CSS to version 5.0 or you'll have to update the  tag:

**Versions < 5.0:**

`<i class="fa fa-facebook">`

**Versions => 5.0:**

`<i class="fab fa-facebook">`